# Power options for pricing European claims

Tags: options, option-pricing, moments

I have the following question:

Why would somebody be interested in the expression $E[S^\theta]$ for $\theta$ between zero and one.
The only thing I know is that this then can be somehow used to compute the call option price $(S-k)^+$.

Comment: I suspect you may be struggling with the concept of 'characteristic function', which is defined as 
\begin{align}
\psi_{\log S_T}(u) &= E_t \left[ \exp\left\{ iu \log \left(\frac{S_T}{ S_t}\right)\right\} \right] \\
&= E_t \left[ \left(\frac{S_T}{S_t}\right)^{iu} \,\right]
\end{align}
with $u\in \mathbb R$. 

Fourier inversion of the characteristic function will give you the distribution, which you can then use to calculate the option price.

Comment: Thank you Frido, I do understand that concept. The issue I am having is that $\theta$ is only defined for the interval $(0,1)$ so I do not know what $S_T^{iu}$ is.

Comment: Ok, well I have not come across this particular problem before. As mentioned before, if you can give more details then perhaps I or others can be more helpful.